# Is it possible to have a wireless network and a wired network simultaneously, and to have different applications use one or the other?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is it possible to have a wireless network and a wired network simultaneously, and to have different applications use one or the other?

For instance, to have Chrome use the wireless network, while everything else goes through the wired network?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Network Manager.

Thanks!

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: The only way to do this would be having an application-aware firewall that can handle which routes data takes.  However, this is not trivial to do and there is no inbuilt mechanism to do this, so unless you want to try and write something yourself or pay a software company to do that for you you won't be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the routing table to change the network interface based on the **destination** of the traffic.  There isn't a simple way to choose the network interface based on application.  If your use case is a wired network that does not have internet access, then you can route the IP ranges it uses to use the wired and everything else to use the wireless.  If your use case is that you want to be able to browse the internet without prying eyes that are on that network, you could setup a proxy server.  Many applications support proxies, whether it's a SOCKS proxy or HTTP.  From there you could route anything going to your proxy over the wifi.  Any applications that are accessing a specific set of IP addresses can also be routed over the Wifi by using the route command with the specified IP addresses.

To change the route of a single host like a proxy to use the wifi:

```
# route add -host 192.168.1.2 dev wlan0
```

Or a block of IPs:

```
# ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
```

Another example to route all remaining traffic to a specific device

```
# ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be very helpful. So I could route all google traffic through wifi like this, leaving other traffic on eth0? ----- ip route add 142.250.73.0/24 dev wlan0

Comment: @smwilsonau Assuming your network device is wlan0, yes.  Though you say 'google' traffic, do you mean google searching?  You might get the results going over the wifi, but the individual pages you click on after that would go through the wire.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Although your answer is not exactly the answer to my original question, I'm marking it correct because I think this approach is going to solve my problem and it's a very useful thing to know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

i never tried it myself though , i think it must be achievable through virtual box, since you can attach different hardware to the VM

Comment: This is a valid answer, can you add more details to the answer on how to do this?

Comment: I agree, this would probably work. But I'd rather not be running another whole virtual OS just to support a particular application. But I'll mark as correct because I think this is a viable option.